# Send JSON object as a form array

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I need to POST some data to a URL. I need to get my object:

```
var profile = {
    firstname: first_name,
    lastname: last_name,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    mobile: mobile,
    address_1: address_1,
    address_2: address_2,
    city: city,
    postcode: postcode,
};
```

to send to the endpoint like a form would. ie an array

```
profile[firstname] = "Billy"
profile[lastname] = "Jones"
...
```

My header `Content-Type`:

```
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
```

For some reason I can't figure out how to send it as a form array and not a JSON string.

Comment: are u using jquery to send it?

Comment: @VladIoffe nope developing a titanium app using there network client  - http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient

Comment: Why not use a json string ? It is very easy to desrialize it to a Dictionary<string, object> or key value pair list on the server side depending on the serializer you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the object, converting each property and it's value to a key-value pair.

You'll need to wrap each key with `profile[` and `]` due to your additional requirement.

Then add `&` between them.

```
var data = [];
for (var prop in profile) {
    if (profile.hasOwnProperty(prop) {
        data.push(encodeURIComponent("profile[" + prop + "]") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(profile[prop]);
    }
}
var urlencoded = data.join("&");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the below?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setContentHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { /* whatever */ };
xhr.send("firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname + "...");
```

Of course, this code is not production ready. Just an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var profile = {}; 
    profile.firstname = first_name,
    profile.lastname = last_name,
    profile.email = email,
    profile.phone = phone,
    profile.mobile = mobile,
    profile.address_1 = address_1,
    profile.address_2 = address_2,
    profile.city = city,
    profile.postcode = postcode,
      $.ajax({
                url: "url",
                data: "{profile:" + JSON.stringify(profile ) + "}",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: onSussess,
                error: onError
            });
```